# Ultimate points mod in phpBB3 not displaying on the front end.

Tags: phpbb3

I'm using phpBB3 for my forums and have installed the Ultimate points mod. Its working perfectly on the backend, tacking users points ect, but it is not publicly displaying them.

www.rise-co.com/phpBB3

I have followed these instructions

http://www.rise-co.com/UltimatePoints/install.xml

But keep getting a parse error, like its not defined properly.

Answer (score 0):

What version do you have installed? All the version up to 1.1.2 have issues and will not install properly via AutoMod. A developer ported this mod into a great style plus updated it to work with phpBB 3.0.12.

This is the link for the MOD download updated: http://www.sitesplat.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=7&p=3813#p3813

But you need to be part of the members who bought FLATBOOTS style to have access to it, amazing style by the way. This is the style link just in case: http://themeforest.net/item/flatboots-phpbb3-/8536771?ref=ThemeSplat